# Windows not booting after changing EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity setting in GroupPolicy

Tags: windows, windows-11, group-policy, recovery

Today I wanted to disable the Microsoft Defender Credential Guard on my Windows 11 workstation to allow my remote connections to use stored passwords again (LAN only, no domain login). I did, however, not want to disable virtualization based security alltogether, so I changed the group policy (this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-deviceguard) from "not configured" to "enabled", but selected "disabled" for CredentialGuard.

Doing so, I noticed that EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity was set to "Enabled without lock" and figured I could just change it to locked, as I do only use the computer physically anyway.

After rebooting, Windows does not start up anymore.

I can use the recovery console to access all drives (BitLocker Recovery code needed obviously), but I do not know how to fix the error, as I do not fully understand why WIndows does not boot up. Any clues?

(Potentially relevant: Hyper-V was not installed on my system, Google indicates it has to before the virtualization based security to work. However, as stated, the default value seemed to be "Enabled" already, even though the entire policy was set at "not configured")

Comment: Can the PC boot in Safe mode? If so, can the setting be changed back there?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik it cannot boot into Safe Mode, I can only access the recorvery tools.

Comment: @JohannesH. - The first step would be to disable BitLocker protection, BitLocker protection probably should have been suspended before you took your actions, as a safe guard.

Comment: @Ramhound I can do that no problem to make changes in the system. However,this will still not make any UI available to me, so I still need to address the point of actually fixing the problem from within the recovery console.

Comment: Well once you disable BitLocker you have more options available to you. Unfortunately your in your current situation due to your own actions, and not fully understanding, what you were enabling. BitLocker makes the job fixing your situation nearly impossible. It can always be renabled after your system is bootable

Comment: @Ramhound I fully agree with this. I did decrypt the drive, safe mode however does still not work, so I am still left with the recovery console - only I do not need to enter a bit locker key anymore now. So I am not exactly sure, what "more options" you imply in your comment. Could you give me a clue?

Comment: 1. Make a disk image *as it is now*, lest data be come unrecoverable. 2. Try downloading the Windows ISO to USB and reinstall it, trying to keep files. 3. If that does not make your system bootable, reinstall completely.

Comment: I do have a full data backup, losing data is not an issue. Just using the installation, along with WSL and WSA installations and several customizations to them. It's mostly Windows settings tuned for Development I care about, I can redo them all but it takes time. This is the reason I prefer to recover the installation, not reinstall it. Reinstalling I can do without help.

Comment: A complete reinstall of windows did NOT fix this issue. I can boot with CSM enabled (it will use UEFI to boot though). I can also boot if I disable CPU Virtualization.

Any hint?